# Not able to access TFS on Windows 10

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, windows-10

I'm trying to reach a TFS server (either via VS2015 or Web) from my Windows 10 dev box with no luck. I keep getting timeout error

- This server is on a remote network that I access via VPN.
- I've tried on different Win10 boxes, and it is the same problem.
- People in the local network (no vpn) also tried on Windows 10 with no luck
- If I access the server on a Windows 7 dev box, everything is OK.
- I am able to access a different TFS server (located on my domain network) correctly; same port and protocol.
- I disabled the computer firewall

Any clue?

Comment: Could you ping the remote network or remote connect the server  successfully on your WIndows10 dev box?

Comment: @Patrick-MSFT IP is resolved but I get timeout

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the IP Address such as http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx:8080/tfs instead of http://compandyname:8080/tfs

Comment: I still receive Timeout

Comment: windows authentication NTLM (which TFS uses) will not work. Try to use another Authentication(Team Foundation Server Administration Console--Authentication Settings) Change NTLM to Negotiate(Kerberos) . And try again.